# Method signature in C, passing pointer on static array

Tags: c, pointers, method-signature

I have the following arrays:

```
char* mask[9];
int hSobelMask[9] = {
    -1, -2, -1,
    0, 0, 0,
    1, 2, 1};
```

I want to give a pointer on this array to a method like this:

```
int H = applyMask(&mask, &hSobelMask);
```

The signature of the applyMask function is the folowing:

```
int applyMask(char** mask[9], int* sobelMask[9]);
```

But I get the following compile warning:

```
demo.c: In function ‘customSobel’:
demo.c:232:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘applyMask’ from incompatible pointer type
demo.c:181:5: note: expected ‘char ***’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)[9]’
demo.c:232:7: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘applyMask’ from incompatible pointer type
demo.c:181:5: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[9]’
```

What does this warning mean, how do I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to pass the pointers to these arrays? So you're probably looking for this:

```c
int applyMask(char* (*mask)[9], int (*sobelMask)[9]);
```

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question, unlike the rest of us. (I think the question was misguided, but it's still good to actually answer it!)

Comment: Nice! I was actually curious how this was possible, personally, I would have done with typedefs so I won't have to deal with this kind of syntax. Although now that I think about it, it is starting to make sense

Answer (score 0):

A `char * ___[9]` is an array of `char *`, and a `char * * ___[9]` is an array of `char * *`. They're not compatible. Just change your function signature to this:

```
int applyMask(char** mask, int* sobelMask)
```

or this:

```
int applyMask(char* mask[], int sobelMask[])
```

**Edited to add** (after Shahbaz's comment below): Call your function like this:

```
int H = applyMask(mask, hSobelMask);
```

There's no need for those `&`s, since an array variable already is a pointer to the contents of the array.

Comment: He wants to send a pointer to the arrays, not the arrays themselves.

Comment: @Shahbaz: That doesn't make sense. An array basically *is* a pointer -- a constant one -- so getting a pointer *to* it doesn't really serve any purpose.

Comment: If I use your first proposition, I have the following error: `expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)[9]`

Comment: @pinouchon: Good timing; the edit I just made explains how to address that. :-)

Comment: @ruakh Does sending the array like this forces the program to make a copy ? `applyMask(mask, sobelMask);` I think so, and it's the reason why I send a pointer on the array

Comment: @pinouchon: No, no copy. The array "decays" to a pointer, and a pointer is what is sent. (You're probably thinking of `struct`s, where a full copy *is* made unless you pass a pointer. But an array is basically a pointer to begin with, and that pointer is all that's sent.)

Comment: I think you're correct, but let's save the problem of passing the pointer anyway, because it might be useful in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
int applyMask(char** mask, int* sobelMask);
```

Comment: He wants to send a pointer to the arrays, not the arrays themselves

Comment: Makes no sense, since the arrays are not (modifyable) lvalues. (that's the reason why pointers to arrays decay to pointers to their first member)

Comment: Making sense or not, you are not answering the question!

Comment: Yes I am. This should work perfectly. Normally, the OP would have to add a third argument to the function to pass the array sizes.